# C# Send Data Notifications through another project solution (Binding)

Tags: c#, forms, binding, refresh

I've got 2 projects, one containing my model, the other one containing my view (Windows Form).
I tried to refresh my view, specifically a **Label** in accordance with model changes during my build() method using bindings but that didn't work. I don't know if my code is wrong or if it is impossible.

*Edit : Actually, it seems that a label needs an **Update() or Refresh() call** to be updated graphically in his window... That can explain my problem*

there is my Model class  :

```
// ModelBuilder : INotifyPropertyChanged 

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private Substation currentSubstation;

public Substation CurrentSubstation
{
   get
   {
       return this.currentSubstation;
   }
   set
   {
       if (value != this.currentSubstation)
       {
           this.currentSubstation = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentSubstation");
        }
    }
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

 public void Build()
 {
     foreach (Uri substationUri in substationsUri)
     {                 
         Substation substation = new Substation(substationUri); // long process
         this.CurrentSubstation = substation;
     } 
 }
```

There is my view

```
private void StartImportation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.model = new ModelBuilder(); 
   // Old mistake: 
   //this.timeLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.model.CurrentSubstation,"name")); 
   this.timeLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.model, "CurrentSubstation.name")); 
   this.model.Build(); //  I'd like to see the current substation created name
}
```

Comment: Inside **CurrentSubstation** property and in the **set** part you need to pass property name as parameter in the function like this - **NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentSubstation")**

Comment: @KrishnrajRana It stills not work, but even without this argument, my code went inside the NotifyPropertyChanged function. I checked it with a breakpoint.

Comment: It executes your NotifyPropertyChanged() function because you have used optional parameter. so it never throws any error as it just pass blank string inside function. So you'll never get any notification at destination.

Comment: Ok I will let what you told me. So now, i've got                     NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentSubstation"); buts still not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are binding to the initial `this.model.CurrentSubstation` but when you `Build()` the `ModelBuilder` a new `Substation` is assigned. However the old `CurrentSubstation` never changed during that process.

```
new Binding("Text", this.model.CurrentSubstation, "name")
```

Change the binding to

```
new Binding("Text", this.model, "CurrentSubstation.name")
```

Comment: @RedtheoneTowedance Sorry, I thought it was WPF. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Ohhhh yes that resolved my progressBar problem (same kind of binding without property) => this.progressBar.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", this.model, "SubstationCount")); is OK

But the label stills not refresh, but i'm working on it. I hope it will be good on few minutes

Comment: Hmmm it's strange it looks like a Label needs to have a manual Update() to be display correctly. Did you already hear about it ?

Comment: Could the `name` changes after `CurrentSubstation` has been assigned? if this is the case, `Substation` needs to implement INPC as well.

Comment: No, the substation's name never changes. It is just assigned at the creation. The problem comes from Update() non-call I think : Modifiying manually a Label text doesnt update it whitout Refresh() or Update() call method. Currently, the label just takes the first value and is never updated.

Comment: But without Update() call just after binding my label (default Substation = first one), the label is just empty and never changes...